# Producer-Consumer multiple producers multiple queues single consumer

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, producer-consumer

We have a general logging problem where we do 3 types of logging (lets just say: tracing, auditing, counting) are the 3 areas of logging we do. And we do them all at the same time, from code running within a REST web service, for each web request that comes in.

For each request that is made, we make many calls to each of the logging areas. Lets say, on average about 100 logging calls in total for each web request, some tracing, some audits, some counters, total 100 calls, each web request. Each logging call writes some data to some store for processing later [Not important what the store is, but getting it into that store is definitely I/O bound - (actually it is an azure queue, so its a HTTP call across the interweb)].

Our problem is that the act of logging any information (in either of the 3 areas) takes the service request thread far too long to write to all the log sinks 100 times. We have measured up to 4/5ths of the request processing time is spent writing to logging sinks! So, you can see we need to optimize that significantly!

We want to speed things up, and free the request thread from log writing. We want to use another thread to do the writing of logging data to the 3 logging stores at its own pace in the background. So we think queuing up the logging writes in a memory queue so that the log writing thread can process them in parallel with multiple requests coming in, is a way to go.

Stephen Cleary's book 'Concurrency in C# Cookbook' (fab reference) identifies that using a blocking collection like `BlockingCollection<T>` would be ideal in this situation. So that one thread at a time can produce the data (and write to the memory queue), and another thread can consume the data from the memory queue. Seems like it would be ideal for our situation.

However, in our case, because we are running in an ASP.NET host, and thread pool threads are very precious to the web server (for scalability), we will only want to have one thread dedicated to [consuming] all 3 logging queues. Leaving all other threads to handle inbound web requests, and [produce] logging data.

So the problem becomes: how to use 3 instances of `BlockingCollection<T>` (one for each type of logging), and support:

1. Any number of producers [inbound web request threads] for producing data
2. A single (dedicated) logging thread consumer, that consumes all three queues, all of the time continuously and efficiently.

Can anyone think of a design pattern that would work well here? The missing piece for us, is how a consumer can efficiently empty all three queues, without blocking on any of them, and continuously process all three of them.

Comment: You could have a single `BlockingCollection<T>` where `T` is some custom class that can contain any of the three types. You can use an enum inside this type to detect which type this class really holds.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not seeing from your answer how we process all three `BlockingCollection<T>` queues with the same consumer thread, continuously without waiting on any one of those queues.

Comment: I am suggesting that you have a single `BlockingCollection`, not three.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for the clarification. The enum describes the data, which ultimately helps the consumer decide which store to add it to. Yes, that could work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pattern that I've used successfully in similar scenarios.

First, I typically use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` because there is no scenario where anything needs to block. Perhaps that will vary based on the volume of your logging. The queue is contained in a `Buffer` class. It could just well contain multiple queues.

All the request thread does is put items in the queue. On that same thread the `Buffer` is checking the quantity against a maximum size, and if it determines the need to flush the buffer it does so on a separate thread. There's also a timer so that the buffer gets flushed even if it's not full. In either case there's a check to ensure that the buffer isn't already flushing.

The result is that unless the buffer is perpetually full there doesn't need to be a thread always dedicated to the log, blocking when there are no messages.

You can also increase performance by sending messages to the queue in batches rather than individually. You can remove a lot of overhead by sending one "message" containing 50-100 messages rather than sending each one separately.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, some good ideas here, and some of the optimizations you suggest make some sense in our scenario. I particularly like the addition of the timeout as well as the max threshold. Are you suggesting that we kick of the logging thread (from request thread) using Task.Run()?

Comment: Yes. I had a generic implementation of this but I can't find it, so I'm writing it again. The idea is a generic `ISink<T>` interface, and `BufferedSink<T>` is an implementation. That in turn contains another `ISink<T>` that it writes to. It also depends on an `IBufferedSinkSettings` interface which contains max buffer size, timer interval, and can also specify whether the flush to the inner buffer should be synchronous.